# How to config Zend Frameword 2 output cache

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm using output cache in zend framework 2:

```
$outputCache = Zend\Cache\PatternFactory::factory(
  'output', 
  array(
    'storage' => 'apc'
  )
);

$outputCache->start('mySimpleViewScript');
include '/path/to/view/script.phtml';
$outputCache->end();
```

Please help me config time `cache(ttl)` and `cache_dir`.

Thanks.

Comment: You use apc as a storage, this is an in-memory cache. If you want to write to a directory, use the file system cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass storage by string ('apc' in your example), specific storage implementation is pulled from `Zend\Cache\Storage\AdapterPluginManager` as invokable with default options (ttl is 0 by default).

If you need custom options, just create your cache storage directly, it is covered by [cache storage adapter documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.cache.storage.adapter.html#quick-start):

```
$cache = Zend\Cache\StorageFactory::factory([
    'adapter' => [
        'name'    => 'apc',
        'options' => [ 'ttl' => 3600 ],
    ],
]);

$outputCache = Zend\Cache\PatternFactory::factory('output', [
    'storage' => $cache,
]);
```

`cache_dir` is not valid option for Apc adapter.